# Exercises about subgroup generated by $[h,k]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H, K \leq G. $ Let
$G' = [H,K]$ be a subgroup of $G$ which generated by all 
$[h,k]$ with $ h \in H , k \in K $. Show that:

$1)$ $H\subseteq C_{G}(K)$ iff $[H,K]=1$

$2)$ $H\subseteq N_{G}(K)$ iff $[H,K]\subseteq K$

$3)$ If $H,K$ normal subgroups of $G$ and $H \cap K = 1$ then $H\subseteq C_{G}(K)$.

My effort:

$1)$ $[H,K]=1$ so all $[h,k]=1$ so all the elements of $H,K$ commute.

$H \subset C_{G}(K)$ so if $h \in H$ then $h \in C_{G}(K)$ so $hk=kh$ for all $k \in K$ which is correct since elements of $H,K$ commute.

(Is that ok?)

$2)$

$3)$ $[H,K] \subset K$

$[H,K]^{-1} = [K,H] \subset H$ so $[H,K] \subset H$. So $[H,K] \subset H \cap K =1$ so all the elements of $H,K$ commute and we have the same as part $1$.

(Is that ok?)

Comment: The definition of $G'$ in the question does not match the one in your attempt to answer it. Also, please ask one question at a time.

Comment: $C_G(K) = C(G) \cap K$ ?

Comment: @Shaun Oh you' re right! how about the rest of my attempt?

Comment: @infinity $$C_{G}(K)= \begin{Bmatrix}
g \in G | gkg^{-1} = k \ ,\forall k \in K 
\end{Bmatrix}$$
$$N_{G}(K)= \begin{Bmatrix}
g \in G | gKg^{-1} = K 
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

1)seems  fine, I would just add a conclusion such as "hence [h,k]=e $\forall h\in H,k\in K$".

For 2), assume $H\subset N_G(K)$. Let $h\in H , k\in K$ , we must show $[h,k]\in K$.

By assumption , $h\in N_G(K)$ so $hKh^{-1}=K$ so $hkh^{-1} = k' \in K$ so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1} = k'k^{-1} \in K$ since $K $ is a subgroup and thus closed to multiplication.

So indeed $[H,K]\subset K$.

Now assume $[H,K]\subset K$. Let $h\in H$. we want to show that $h\in N_G(K)$ , that is $hKh^{-1}=K$. But, for any $k \in K$ , $[h,k]=hkh^{-1}k^{-1} \in K$ by assumption, so $hkh^{-1}\in Kk = K$ so indeed $hKh^{-1}=K$ and we have $h\in N_G(K)$.

For 3) , by 1) we need to show that $[H,K] = 1$. 
So let $h\in H$ and $k\in K$. then $hkh^{-1} \in K$ since $K$ is normal. 
So $[h,k] =hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in K $.
On the other hand, $kh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H$ since $H$ is normal, and aain $[h,k] =hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H $. So we get $[h,k]\in H\cap K$. By assumption , $H\cap K=1$ and we are done.